# Tap water fountain to fill up bottle airside at Malaga Airport (AGP)

Tags: airports, airport-terminals, tap-water, malaga

I want to fill up an empty bottle which I bring with me.

Are there any tap water fountains inside and after the security checks at Malaga Airport (AGP)?

And if there are, where are they located?

Answer (score 2):

[wateratairports](https://www.wateratairports.com/topic/malaga-agp-airport/) suggests there are several water fountains at Malaga airport and that their locations are marked on the map boards on display at the airport.